# Failing with a python bubble sort

Tags: python

I've written this code and I want it to organise the player scores.

```
file = open("leaderboard.txt", "a")
file.write(str(winnerscore)+ ": " + winner + "\n")
file.close()
fileReading = open("leaderboard.txt","r")
lines = fileReading.read()
fileReading.close()
lines = lines.split("\n")
for line in lines:
    print(line)

def bubbleSort(arr):
    n = len(arr) 

    for i in range(n-1): 

        for j in range(0, n-i-1): 


            if arr[j] > arr[j+1] : 
                arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j] 

# Driver code to test above 
arr = int(float(lines[0]))

bubbleSort(arr) 

print ("Sorted array is:") 
for i in range(len(arr)): 
    print ("%s" %arr[i])
```

It produces this but doesn't sort it:

```
76: Daniel
36: Gabriel
30: Perry
92: Avi
28: Yehuda
46: Jeremy
54: Mordechai
96: Paul
80: Pauline
72: Fran
```

Unfortunately it comes up with this error message:

```
  arr = int(float(lines[0]))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '76: Daniel'
How do I fix this so it sorts from highest score to lowest score?
```

How do I make it so that it sorts the scores in the list?

Comment: Are you intended to write a sort algorithm yourself or can you use a ready library as [HakanC suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62303333/711006)?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are comaparing items like `if 76: Daniel>36: Gabriel` 
You can try something like this

```
mylist=['76: Daniel','36: Gabriel','30: Perry','92: Avi','28: Yehuda','46: Jeremy','54: Mordechai','96: Paul','80: Pauline','72: Fran']

def bubbleSort(arr):
    n=len(arr)
    for i in range(n-1): 

        for j in range(0, n-i-1): 


            if int(arr[j][:2]) < int(arr[j+1][:2]) : 
                arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j] 
bubbleSort(mylist)
print(mylist)
>>>['96: Paul', '92: Avi', '80: Pauline', '76: Daniel', '72: Fran', '54: Mordechai', '46: Jeremy', '36: Gabriel', '30: Perry', '28: Yehuda']
```

Comment: It says that there is no module named 'sortedcontainers'

Comment: Yeah @BenjaminHirschfield, `sortedcontainers` doesn't works for this problem. I edited my answer, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty obvious and Python tells you where the problem is: You are explicitly trying to convert the whole first line (`lines[0]`) which contains characters to a number.

Extracting just the first line to `arr` and the ongoing sort of this single line would be useless. Moreover, conversion to `float` and then to `int` is definitely not necessary.

If all the numbers are equally long (2 characters), you can simply sort your lines as strings (not numbers) by simply leaving out the conversion.
You can simply change the erroneous line to

```
arr = lines
```

to make your program work. (Or rename all the following `arr` references to `lines`, of course.)

I’d also remove the first 3 lines of your program which are currently unrelated to the rest of your program.

[See the result online.](https://ideone.com/WRhFHA)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
string1 = lines[0]
int(re.search(r'\d+', string1).group())
```

Instead of arr = int(float(lines[0])), try using the above one. String1 contains the integer values. On that apply the bubble sort.

Answer (score 0):

Short way to use :)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('leaderboard.txt', delimiter=":", names=('scor', 'Name'))
df.sort_values(by='scor', inplace=True)
df.head()

    scor        Name
7    96        Paul
3    92         Avi
8    80     Pauline
0    76      Daniel
9    72        Fran
6    54   Mordechai
5    46      Jeremy
1    36     Gabriel
2    30       Perry
4    28      Yehuda

arr = df.values
```

Comment: IMHO it would be simpler to use the native Python `sort` function than import Pandas here...